# Composer Fatal error: Declaration of Fxp... must be compatible with ...AbstractAssetsRepository.php on line 334

Tags: php, linux, laravel, command-line, composer-php

I updated composer

```
composer self-update
```

I installed the newer version of the plugin

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

I try to install Laravel

**composer global require "laravel/installer"**

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Arthur/AppData/Roaming/Composer    
Fatal error: Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRe
    pository::search() must be compatible with Composer\Repository\RepositoryInterfa
    ce::search($query, $mode = 0, $type = NULL) in C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Roaming\C
    omposer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository.php
     on line 334
```

Now all commands in composer not working

```
composer <any command>
```

Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can temporarily disable composer plugins with the `--no-plugins` option:

```
composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

See Composer docs - [Global options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options):

> --no-plugins: Disables plugins.

Answer (score 9):

To solve the above error while installing composer asset plugin please do the following

1. delete fxp folder in the path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor
2. remove `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.4"`  from composer.json file in composer folder
3. run this command
   `composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins`
   to make sure no fxp folder is left and json data
4. `composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins`
   Run this command to install composer asset plugin and it will be installed easily
5. If you want to update existing plugin, run this command

   `composer global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins`

Comment: Ran into this problem. This solved it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

according to this decision here

[composer error when run composer update](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9794)

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/fxp
```